# Yii2: Mail with view is not being sent

Tags: php, email, yii2, swiftmailer

I am trying to send email in `Yii2` with a `view` but it's not sent. Here is what I am doing in `controller`:

```
$message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose('reportview-html', [
                            'positiveReviews' => $positiveReviews,
                            'negativeReviews' => $negativeReviews,
                            'company_name' => $userSurveyConfig->survey_email_from
                        ])->setFrom([\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => "Review Fox"])
                        ->setTo($userSurveyConfig->reports_email_address)
                        ->setSubject("Review Fox Weekly/Monthly Report")
                        ->send();
```

And this is my `config` setting for mail:

```
'mail' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@frontend/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => false, //set this property to false to send mails to real email addresses
//comment the following array to send mail using php's mail function
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'username' => '**********************',
                'password' => '********',
                'port' => '465',
                'encryption' => 'ssl',
            ],
        ],
```

When I run the script it doesn't simply send the `email` but when I try to send the email without view, simple plain text in body, It does send the email.
What am i doing wrong? Any help?

Comment: I know that you have the path set in the config itself, can you try commenting out that and try this directly ** Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@frontend/mail/layouts/reportview-html',['model' => $model, 'path' => $path,'password' => $password])**

Comment: @MohanPrasad tried it, but the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change your port and encryption type, might work for you.

```
 'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
                'transport' => [
                    'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                    'username' => '*******',
                    'password' => '*****',
                    'port' => '587',
                    'encryption' => 'tls',
                ]

        ],
```

It works fine for me, have different mail layouts setup and everything is working fine.

I hope this tutorial might be helpful for you.[click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e_oWwnMpHqY)

Setup your mail/layouts/html file like the below code:

```
    <?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this \yii\web\View view component instance */
/* @var $message \yii\mail\MessageInterface the message being composed */
/* @var $content string main view render result */
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>" />
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php $this->beginBody() ?>
    <?= $content ?>
    <?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

And now you can go ahead and create your other layouts like below for instance.

```
   <?php
use yii\helpers\Html;

/* @var $this \yii\web\View view component instance */
/* @var $message \yii\mail\MessageInterface the message being composed */
/* @var $content string main view render result */
?>
<?php $this->beginPage() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .mail-wrapper{ border: 1px solid #ddd2d2; box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888888;}
        .mail-font{ font-size: 18px; padding:15px 25px; margin-left:10px !important; margin-top: 10px !important;}
        .mail-button{ text-decoration: none; border: 1px solid #2A3F54; background-color: #2A3F54; color: white; box-shadow: 0 0 5px #FCB3BC; }
        .mail-button:hover {background-color: #286090 !important;}
    </style>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<?= Yii::$app->charset ?>" />
    <title><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></title>
    <?php $this->head() ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?php $this->beginBody() ?>

    <div class="mail-wrapper">

        <div class="mail-font fa fa-paw">
            <img src ="<?= $message->embed($path); ?>" />
        </div>
        <br></br>


        <div class="mail-font">
            <?= "This e-mail and any attachments may contain confidential material for the sole
                use of the intended recipient(s). Any review or distribution by others is
                strictly prohibited. If you are not the intended recipient, please contact the
                sender and delete all copies..  "; ?>
        </div>
                <br></br>

    </div>


    <?php $this->endBody() ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php $this->endPage() ?>
```

Comment: I have tried this, it didn't work. Still the same results.

Comment: did you change the port?

Comment: As far as I know you are not outputting the content in the html file.. you do that it should work fine..tested the above code..